# Linq count rows

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a linq query on a datatable. I'm trying to get a count of my previous linq query.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq

Sub TestThis()
    Dim t As New testLinq
    t.testLinqCount()
End Sub

Class testLinq

    Sub testLinqCount()
        'create new datatable
        Dim myQbCustTable As New DataTable
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Dim col As New DataColumn
            myQbCustTable.Columns.Add(col)
        Next

        'add rows
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Dim rw As DataRow = myQbCustTable.NewRow
            rw.Item(1) = 1200 + i
            myQbCustTable.Rows.Add(rw)
        Next

        'linq query
        Dim CustBalQuery = From Cust In myQbCustTable _
                           Select CustomerID = Cust.Item(1), _
                                    CustQBName = Cust.Item(2), _
                                    CustBal = Cust.Item(3) _
                                    Order By CustomerID

        'get count
        Dim ct As Integer = CustBalQuery.Count() '<error here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can you tell me how to get a count of CustBalQuery? I tried `CustBalQuery.Count()` and got this error: Public member 'Count' on type 'OrderedEnumerableRowCollection(Of VB$AnonymousType_7(Of Object,Object,Object))' not found.

Comment: Summing customer IDs look like a very odd approach to me. I'd expect `CustBalQuery.Count()` to be what you want...

Comment: @JonSkeet see edited post for error message

Comment: Do you have an import for System.Linq? Note that I suggested Count() rather than count... It may well not make a differnce given VB's implicit brackets and case-insensitivity, but I'd still try it in the same way I suggested...

Comment: @JonSkeet I do have System.Linq. I tried using `.Count()` as you suggested but got the same error. I'm using VS 2008 and VB.net 3.5. Is this a version problem?

Comment: I wouldn't expect so. It would really help if you'd post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (It doesn't need to do any of your "real" logic - it only needs to demonstrate the problem and be complete so that we can reproduce it.)

Comment: @JonSkeet OK I edited my Q with a simple example. Should be reproducible. Hope it's OK that I used an existing datatable.

Comment: No, that's still not a short but complete example. We should be able to copy the example straight into a text file, compile it and see the error.

Comment: @JonSkeet This edit should do it. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Nope, that still isn't complete. Where are the imports? Where's the class declaration? Where's the method declaration? (It's getting a lot closer though...)

Comment: @Oliver I tried your suggestion but got the same error as before.

Comment: @JonSkeet Got the imports and a sub. Do I need a class for this?

Comment: Put it this way: have you tried just copying your code into a new text file and compiling it? That's what I'm expecting to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I don't know how to do that; I'll google it.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is strange: I put the code in a new console project and it works fine. But in my regular program it throws an error. I'm checking what is different. Version VB.net is same.

Comment: @JonSkeet In my regular program I'm getting CustBalQuery type is object. But in my new console program (using exact same code) the CustBalQuery type is OrderedEnumerableRowCollection. Is there a way to force the CustBalQuery to be enumerable?

Comment: I'd expect it to be already. I would work on finding the differences between your console app and your regular program. You claim it's the "exact same code" but I strongly suspect it's not, in an area that you haven't been looking at (e.g. imports or assembly references).

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot for your help yesterday. I used a workaround for now; I'll look at this again when I have time. It was very illuminating to see my code work in a new project. I can see that getting the right type of object will be key.

Comment: @JonSkeet I found the problem: Option Infer was set to off because it was an upgrade project. http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/linqlangopinf.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option Infer needs to be on. When a project is upgraded it will sometimes turn Option Infer to off in the properties page compile tab. When I set Option Infer On the problem disappeared.

[Option Infer, A VB.NET compile option just for LINQ By Dan Mabbutt](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/linqlangopinf.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I created one dummy type, and it is working as expected:-

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim fruits As New List(Of Fruits)
        Dim fruit1 As New Fruits
        fruit1.FruitID = 1
        fruit1.FruitName = "Apple"
        fruits.Add(fruit1)

        Dim fruit2 As New Fruits
        fruit2.FruitID = 2
        fruit2.FruitName = "Banana"
        fruits.Add(fruit2)

        Dim fruit3 As New Fruits
        fruit3.FruitID = 3
        fruit3.FruitName = "Grapes"
        fruits.Add(fruit3)

        Dim query = From fruit In fruits
                    Select FruitID = fruit.FruitID, FruitName = fruit.FruitName
                    Order By FruitID

        Dim queryCount As Integer = query.Count()
        Console.WriteLine(queryCount)  //Getting output as 3
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure yet how to fix it, but I found my problem thanks to Jon Skeet's help. When I put the code in a new project, it worked right away.

```
'linq query
Dim CustBalQuery = From Cust In myQbCustTable _
                       Select CustomerID = Cust.Item(1), _
                                CustQBName = Cust.Item(2), _
                                CustBal = Cust.Item(3) _
                                Order By CustomerID
```

In my old project `CustBalQuery` was an "Object" type. In my new project `CustBalQuery` is an `OrderedEnumerableRowCollection(Of VB$AnonymousType_7(Of Object,Object,Object))` type.

I'm not sure why this is happening, but this is the reason `CustBalQuery.Count()` is not working in my old project.